# How to open the project from GitHub in Android studio? Troubles with Maven and android support libraries.

Tags: android, git, maven, github, android-studio

I'm starting to use Android Studio. I'd like to open project from GitHub
https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders

On first screen I click 'Check out from Version Control', 'GitHub', select place on disk. 
After cloning I have a question 'You have checked out an Android Studio project file… Would you like to open it?', I agree. 
Than I agree to auto-import for Maven project. 
Than I find the project 'Examples', try to build it and get 'No resource found that matches the given name Theme:AppCompat', and import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity does not work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ph04ogcr2txmge3/Screenshot%202014-07-24%2017.42.22.png

What to do to make the example app? Requirement is to save the project structure for using 'git status' and 'git diff' commands.

Answer (score 2):

There are several SO questions on this topic, but @MartinRevert's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978323/5025060) is the only one I found mentioning Android Studio's (AS's) Gradle dependency.  If the Github project was built with Eclipse, importing it to AS will work but **the result will not be buildable with AS** (indication: the project's "Make project" icon is grayed out in AS).

Building on Martin's answer, and using IntelliJ's [Migrating From Eclipse Projects](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects) page as a reference, I found a simple and transparent way to import an Eclipse-based Github project into AS 2.1.2:

1. Import the Github project using AS:
   `File->New->Project from Version Control->Github`
   This clones the Github project, but if it is not a Gradle Project (see above), follow these additional steps:
2. Create a new project using:
   `File->New->Import Project` and click on the folder you stored the project to in step (1) above.  Accept all of the defaults and AS will "import" the Eclipse project to a Gradle project which it will now be able to build.
3. You may now delete (using a native directory removal tool) the project you created in (1) above.

Related questions:

- [Android Studios - import project from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33594224/5025060)
- [How to import an existing project from github into Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25348339/5025060)

Answer (score 1):

The project is not a Gradle Project, so it is not compatible with Android Studio yet.

I recommend to check out from Github inside Eclipse and export as a 'Gradle Project'.

Then, proceed to import that project into Android Studio.