# How to import an existing project from GitHub into Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, import

I've just imported the "EdgeEffectOverride" project from Github into Android Studio.

This is the screen shot.
[image]

When I run the project, I get the error: `Error running build: Module 'EdgeEffectOverride-master' is not backed by gradle`.

Comment: I think I may have answered this question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38312577/5025060.

Answer (score 54):

You can directly import GitHub projects into Android Studio.

**File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> GitHub.** Then enter your GitHub username and password. Select the repository and hit **clone.**

The GitHub repo will be created as a new project in Android Studio.

Comment: When I do this, I don't get the gradle build stuff.

Answer (score 25):

Unzip the github project to a folder. Open Android Studio. Go to **File -> New -> Import Project**. Then choose the specific project you want to import and then click Next->Finish. It will build the Gradle automatically and'll be ready for you to use.

P.S: In some versions of Android Studio a certain error occurs-
error:**package android.support.v4.app does not exist.**
To fix it go to Gradle Scripts->build.gradle(Module:app) and the add the dependecies:

```
dependencies {      
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
}
```

Enjoy working in Android Studio

Comment: This approach of downloading he Zip file, unzipping it and then opening the project from Android Studio worked better for us. It saved us a lot of time.

Comment: After doing this, what's the best way to connect it to the github repository?

Answer (score 16):

In Github click the "Clone or download" button of the project you want to import  --> download the ZIP file and unzip it. In Android Studio **Go to File -> New Project -> Import Project** **and select the newly unzipped folder -> press OK.** It will build the Gradle automatically.

Good Luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Download the Zip from the website or clone from Github Desktop.
   Don't use VCS in android studio.
2. (Optional)Copy the folder extracted into your AndroidStudioProjects folder which must contain the hidden .git folder.
3. Open Android Studio-> File-> Open-> Select android directory.
4. If it's a Eclipse project then convert it to gradle(Provided by
   Android Studio). Otherwise, it's done.