# Importing older gradle projects into android studio

Tags: android

How do i import a project downloaded from github which is based on an older gradle version (2.0.0)? 
here is my build.gradle-

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

whenever i change the gradle version to 2.1.2 (which is the gradle version used by all my projects), the project gets stuck on the "building.." message and never imports-

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

I even tried replacing the whole build.gradle file with the one in my projects, and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do after importing project from Github

There are two gradle files as shown is picture

[image]

In first gradle file replace class path with yours

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

now in other gradle file as shown in figure
[image]

replace these below lines with yours

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

**and**

```
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

If there are dependencies on libraries than you would require to change them too

Comment: i replaced both gradle files and its stuck on building

Answer (score 0):

1. Also try to check root gradle file and properties.
2. Use default gradle wrapper . It could be found in File->Settings ->Build->Build Tools->gradle.
3. disable InstantRun though its require but could be helpful sometimes.
4. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820788/5576636) .