# Importing a GitHub project to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, github

As recently, I've been looking through Android Templates for Material UI design, as I want to get a feel on how to use the types of pieces in one. But, It's been a struggle. Every one I've done, I got an error when building the module. `AndroidManifest.xml Not Found`

I've looked every where, and it all doesn't apply to me. I am attempting to import a repository from GitHub to Android Studio, all updates installed. Here were my steps.

1. Clone the project into a .zip file.
2. Extract.
3. Import into Android Studio.
4. Import Gradle Files.
5. Configure framework.
6. All works, but only option to generate signed APK, normal apk, and build module.
7. Build Module.
8. Android Manifest isn't found.

Is there something I'm missing? Please let me know, as I am stuck. I've also read I need a local.properties file. I do not have it, so I do not know how to properly add it without messing up.

Thank You.

Comment: "I am attempting to import a repository from GitHub to Android Studio, all updates installed" -- what were some of the repositories that you tried?

Comment: Well, is there a manifest file? You could search where that properties  file goes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673378/where-does-local-properties-go-for-android-project

Answer (score 0):

Refer this, [How to import an existing project from github into Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348339/how-to-import-an-existing-project-from-github-into-android-studio). 
Still not convinced?.
Try these, https://github.com/rdrobinson3/WelcomeToL/issues/2 and https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/issues/24