# Import from github to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, adsense, adsense-api

Hey I am trying to build an android application regarding google adsense.
I want to import the android sample.
https://github.com/Ishaan-Kumar/googleads-adsense-examples

Since I am only interested in android I want to import only this.
https://github.com/Ishaan-Kumar/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/android

I tried to import via VCS in android studio by url https://github.com/Ishaan-Kumar/googleads-adsense-examples.git

But it imported the whole project including all the platforms(PHP,dontnet,ruby).
The thing is I want the android only plus the android files are not detected (I think there is not gradle file in here)

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

Comment: How......when opening a project in Android Studio, the project gets highlighted in file manager and the icon changes to android studio icon.....nothing happens in this case.

Comment: @r4phG I know about SDK tools. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: **Download Zip**. Don't Fork the project or use git command or VCS in android studio.

Step 2: Open Android Studio->New Project->Open->Select android directory.

Step 3: Android Studio tells you this is a eclipse project (Convert it to gradle blah blah). **Hit Next**. This is the time I came to know this is an eclipse project and why android studio is not detecting it.

Step 4: Done.

PS: Thanks to comments(Comment Author has deleted his comment).

Answer (score 2):

Often programmers explain that in there Git Page, some time don't explain. [like it](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io)

Many way to import Github project into your android studio project like this ways

1. use zip git file Like this Step Answer [here]
2. use clone or git in android studio [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348339/how-to-import-an-existing-project-from-github-into-android-studio)
3. use [JitPack](https://jitpack.io) site for better performance and jump filters [can help you](https://jitpack.io/)

**But**

some programmers in Github don't like customizing them project

they try to damage files or redirecting for block modify