# Importing an opensource project into android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to import the following project into android studio 3.2 :
https://github.com/0xPoly/Strongbox

But it looks like I have then problem with gradle :

I first choose the import a project (gradle, Eclipse...) from android studio and choose the folder where I have a copy of the github folder

I have then a Sync failes error with the following message :

> Unsupported method: `BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix()`. The version
>   of Gradle you connect to does not support that method. To resolve the
>   problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you
>   connect to. Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read
>   other information from the model.

I then change in build.gradle 
classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'`
to
classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0'`

and change in gradle-wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

To

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

and hit Try again

Then after downloading the gradle-4.0-all.zip I get the following error :

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0. Searched in the
>   following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0/gradle-4.0.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0/gradle-4.0.jar
>       https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0/gradle-4.0.pom
>       https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0/gradle-4.0.jar

And I still have the same thing with all versions I tried from 3.0 to 4.10.2

I tried adding google() to the repositories just before jcenter() but this did not worked

What should I do ?

Comment: Try these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348339/how-to-import-an-existing-project-from-github-into-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

1. change  `distributionUrl` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` here: https://github.com/0xPoly/Strongbox/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
2. In build.gradle set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'` instead `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'`

Comment: This almost work I was told to The SDK Build Tools revision (21.1.2) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0  and asked to Update Build Tools version and sync project  which I did and then I got the following error
 Process 'command 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1