# how to add changed codes in bit bucket to my android studio

Tags: java, android, github, bitbucket

I'm working with a team, They made some changes in code now I have to add that to my code. How can I do that in Bit bucket. How to add that code in my android studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import an existing project from GitHub into Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348339/how-to-import-an-existing-project-from-github-into-android-studio)

Comment: Did you get my question right?

Comment: It's almost similar But looking at your question now... I feel you just need to enable VCS if not enabled and just pull the changes

Answer (score 0):

Goto your project home directory in git bash command prompt and execute below commands.

a). If you have a branch which is same as branch used by your team in your local then  execute below command.
**git pull origin  your_branch_name**
Here branch name is corresponding to branch name used by your team.

b). Otherwise execute below commands.

1. **git checkout -- .**  (if you don't need current changes in your local)
2. **git fetch origin**
3. **git checkout -b your_branch_name  origin your_branch_name**

Finally execute below commands to see last commit details

1. **git diff HEAD^**       (for last commit diff)
2. **git log**              (to check commits added by users details)