# Android Studios - import project from GitHub

Tags: android, github

I need someone to explain to me how to import a project from github to android studios correctly.
In school i use a macbook pro but since i have a PC and two monitors at home I thought i'd rather use my pc when studying at home - so I shared my project to GitHub from my laptop. From Android studios (on my PC) I have tried:
 the VCS -> Checkout from version control -> git / github.
It succeeds importing the project but it doesnt seem right and it wont compile. Besides that the structure of the project seems odd compared to a project created in Android Studios.
I find it hard to explain but I hope the picture can help you understand what my problem is. I would really like to be able to work on the same project on different computers.

In advance - thank you :)

[Picture: Imported project vs project created in AS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QznnF.png)

Comment: Looks like you are using Gradle. Are you committing the Gradle file to github?

Comment: I cant remember but I have now tried to make a new and clean project, share it on github etc and now everything seems to work. Dont know what went wrong with my other project. Guess i just have to make a new one.

Comment: If your repository is public, you could post the link to it. That's the true way anyone can really understand what you should do

Comment: I think I may have answered this question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38312577/5025060.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `open` ,use `import project`.[image]

Comment: I would appreciate if you could be a little bit more specific :) thank you

Comment: I have tried but it is still looking wrong. Maybe I  diod something wrong when i pushed the project to GitHub. I'll let you know when i find out